# How can I find out which version of Zurb Foundation I'm running

Tags: zurb-foundation

Is there something I can enter in the command line to find out which version I'm running?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Without knowing more about your exact situation, the easiest way is to add the following JavaSscript after you initialize Foundation (`$(document).foundation();`).

The final product would look like this:

```
$(document).foundation(); 
$(document).ready(function(){
    alert('Foundation Core Version: ' + Foundation.version);
    alert('Foundation DropDown Version:' + Foundation.libs.dropdown.version);
});
```

The first alert gives you the core version of foundation you are running in foundation.js and foundation.min.js.

If you are not using foundation.min.js, which loads Foundation Core and all JavaScript plugins such as: accordion, dropdown, joyride, tab, and so on, you can use the second alert. It will give you the version of the specified plugin.

You can visit the Foundation Docs on [JavaScript Setup](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/javascript.html%22JavaScript%20Setup%22) to learn more about foundation.min.js and the plugins such as: foundation.accordion.js, foundation.dropdown.js, foundation.joyride.js, foundation.tab.js and so on.

I have only tested the JavaScript on **Foundation 5.0.3**, but I believe it will work on older versions.

I hope that helps.

Comment: Excellent. You can also simply open up the browser console on your website and type in ```Foundation.version```

Comment: This helped out a lot.

Answer (score 5):

search in foundation.js for "version"

window.Foundation = {
    name : 'Foundation',

```
version : '5.3.1',
```

Comment: Simplicity always works well!

Answer (score 3):

In your browser's dev tool's console, type "Foundation.version"

Answer (score 2):

For anyone looking at an easy way to do this:

To look up a project's foundation version, look into /bower_components/foundation/bower.json

it should have something similar to:

```
"homepage": "https://github.com/zurb/bower-foundation", "_release": "5.2.1",
```

As far as I'm aware there isn't something you can type in to check the version, you can type 'foundation version' but this will likely come back with 1.0.4 which I think is the installer or compass version, it isn't the version of Foundation.

Answer (score 0):

In the foundation.js file, search for 'version'.